# Redirect if authenticated in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I'm using the `Auth` scaffold in `Laravel 5.3` and I've changed the routes for the `auth`. So instead of `/login` and `/register` I use `/signin` and `/signup`.

In `Laravel 5.2` we had this by default in the `auth` middleware,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This would redirect to the `login` route if the user **wasn't** logged in. In `Laravel 5.3` we have this,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This redirects an already logged in user to the default route `/`. So they switched it around in **5.3**. Instead of defining where guest go, we define were logged in users go.

My question is, how would I *natively* to Laravel 5.3 **change** were guests go?

Because at the moment, people who try to access sites protected by the middleware automatically end up at a `/login` route. I would like to change this to `/signin` but I can't find anywhere to customize this behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how would I "natively" to Laravel 5.3 change were guests go?

[Looks like](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L63) there's a new `unauthenticated()` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` which handles unauthenticated users and redirects to `login`.

As this is part of your app, no reason you couldn't customize it to redirect elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! God... I looked everywhere except there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the app.blade.php with JS:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "{{url('/login')}}";    </script>
@endif
```